# Can OpCodes.Jmp be called to transfer control to a method that resides on a different assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

Can Method1 that resides in AssemblyA issue a OpCodes.Jmp to Method1 that resides in AssemblyB? Both methods have same exact signature.

I can't seem to make this work, always getting System.InvalidProgramException : Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

If the redirection is inside the same Assembly, it works.

If possible, please provide example using Reflection.Emit.

Comment: Why are you using `jmp`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to redirect the method to a proxy assembly. But I want to do it with jmp. Is it possible?

Comment: Post executable repro code, please.

Comment: You could jmp to a stub method in the current assembly that calls into the other assembly. Not sure why you need jmp, though. Wouldn't call+ret work as well?

Comment: But why do you want to do it with `jmp`? Is this some misguided attempt to  "improve performance"? What's wrong with a simple method call?

Comment: I've used `jmp` when writing actual CIL rather than emitting, when the method I was writing was pretty much just a wrapper overload and when the assembly was unverifiable anyway. Even then I'm not sure I wouldn't have been better off just `call`ing. I don't think I'd bother when emitting from C#. I certainly wouldn't if the code was otherwise verifiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have missed something. Are both methods static? Do they have the same calling convention?

The following code doesn't reproduce your issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly
                    (new AssemblyName("TestAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("Main");
    var type = module.DefineType("Test");

    var method = type.DefineMethod
                  (
                    "Test", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, 
                    typeof(int), new[] { typeof(string) }
                  );
    var gen = method.GetILGenerator();
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Jmp, typeof(Class1).GetMethod("Test"));

    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type.CreateType());

    var func = (Func<string, int>)
                obj.GetType().GetMethod("Test").CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, int>));
    var result = func("Banana");

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And in a different assembly, the `Test` class:

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static int Test(string hi)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Did you make sure you're not violating any of the restrictions?

- The evaluation stack must be empty when this instruction is executed.
- The calling convention, number and type of arguments at the destination address must match that of the current method.
- The jmp instruction cannot be used to transferred control out of a try, filter, catch, or finally block.

Comment: both metods aren't static. Just simple public void Methods. But have the same signature. Is this the reason why? I can do it without static  on the same assembly...

Comment: @RicardoBarbosa It works fine for me with instance methods as well. Can you post the signatures of the methods? Are they virtual? Implementing an interface?

Comment: Yes you're right Luaan. I got it working now. I am accepting your answer. Thank you very much! BTW do you happen to know a way to do this redirect directly, without having to write a dynamic assembly for the matter. I mean like writing the il instruction bytes into an array?

Comment: @RicardoBarbosa The best I can think of is `DynamicMethod` - that's what `LambdaExpression.Compile` uses. It only makes sense if you're going to invoke it as a delegate, though (as in this sample). Just do `new DynamicMethod("Test", typeof(int), new [] { typeof(string) })`, fill in the IL and then `.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, int>))`.

Comment: Nice one @Luaan, makes perfectly sense. :) Thanks once again!